# Casting a non-generic type to a generic one

Tags: c#, generics

I've got this class:

```
class Foo { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this class

```
class Foo<T> : Foo {
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
public Foo<T> GetSome() {
    Foo foo = GetFoo();

    Foo<T> foot = (Foo<T>)foo;
    foot.Data = GetData<T>();
    return foot;
}
```

What's the easiest way to convert Foo to Foo<T>? I can't cast directly InvalidCastException) and I don't want to copy each property manually (in my actual use case, there's more than one property) if I don't have to. Is a user-defined type conversion the way to go?

Comment: What does `GetFoo` look like?

Comment: It's just a stub. Replace it with new Foo();

Comment: If that is the case, then you have a fundamental problem. Types just cant become other types.

Comment: just a simple question: if you created a simple `Foo` object, how will you be able to cast it to `Foo<T>`? From where should it have the additional `Data`?

Comment: Wondering if this will be easier if I make Foo and Foo<T> both inherit from an abstract base class FooBase with the shared properties....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an explicit conversion from Foo within `Foo<T>`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Name = "Blah";
        Foo<int> newfoo = (Foo<int>)foo;
        Console.WriteLine(newfoo.Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

class Foo<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator Foo<T>(Foo foo)
    {
        Foo<T> newfoo = new Foo<T>();
        newfoo.Name = foo.Name;
        return newfoo;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This only works without inheritance. It appears you are not able to do a user-defined conversion from a base to a derived class. See comments from *Mads Torgersen* here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/14cf27cf-b185-43d6-90db-734d2ca3c8d4/ :

> We have taken the liberty of
>   predefining conversions (casts)
>   between base classes and derived
>   classes, and to make the semantics of
>   the language predictable *we don't
>   allow you to mess with it*.

It looks like you may be stuck with defining a method to turn a Foo into a `Foo<T>`. That, or drop the inheritance. Neither solution sounds particularly ideal.

Comment: OK that's what I thought. Just looking for validation :) Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work: "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed"

Comment: @John Sheehan: His example will work, but not if you have inheritance.

Comment: That's interesting, I did not notice the inheritance. My example works without it. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: A Good Thought... I wasn't aware of this... Thanks for keeping me learning (+1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an `InvalidCastException`, the `Foo` type returned by `GetFoo()` is not `Foo<T>`. You will need to either pass `T` or `typeof(T)` to that function so it can return an instance of `Foo<T>`.

Comment: The cast exception is on the `Foo<T> foot = (Foo<T>)foo;` line, not the return from GetFoo(); That's just a stub to demonstrate the structure.

Comment: My point still stands. Look where the problem comes from, not where it happens.

Comment: It doesn't answer the bigger question though. I already know that cast isn't possible, it's just a demonstration of my intent.

Comment: @John Sheehan: Then see my 2nd sentence in my answer. There are other options too, like passing a new instance of `Foo<T>` into the `GetFoo` method to populate it. If that is not the case, please clarify your question.  :)

Comment: Or make `GetFoo` generic: `Foo<T> GetFoo<T>()`

Comment: @280Z28: You may not want that  :)  `void PopulateFoo(Foo f)` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use copy constructors. Foo implements:

```
class Foo {
     Foo(Foo copy) { ... }
}
```

while Foo shall be constructed using the following:

```
class Bar<T> : Foo {
      Bar(Foo copy) : base(copy) { ... }
}
```

*...Yes. You need to copy member by member, and this should be done in "copy constructor".*